# MobileFirst Analytics dashboard does not show any data

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, analytics

Our MFP Analytics dashboard was working fine until last week.  There is no data shown in the dashboard.  Restart the server does not seem to help either.  The cluster status on the server is RED. What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I've learned that when the cluster status is red, it is likely due to one or more unassigned shards.  The following commands are quite handy and able to solve my issue:

1. To find the list of all shards, use this CURL command:

> curl -XGET http://localhost:9500/_cat/shards

2. To find the list of unassigned shards, use this CURL command:

> curl -XGET http://localhost:9500/_cat/shards | grep UNASSIGNED

3. Once you get the list of unassigned shards, you can initialize them
   with the following command:

> ```
> for shard in $(curl -XGET http://localhost:9500/_cat/shards | grep UNASSIGNED | awk '{print $2}'); do                                    
>
>  curl -XPOST 'localhost:9500/_cluster/reroute' -d '{                    
>   "commands" : [ {                                                      
>         "allocate" : {                                                  
>             "index" : “worklight”,                                
>             "shard" : $shard,                                           
>             "node" : "worklightNode_1234",                              
>             "allow_primary" : true                                      
>         }                                                               
>       }                                                                 
>   ]                                                                     
>  }'                                                                     
>  sleep 5                                                                
> done
> ```

You need to replace the 'node' with the node that the initialized
shards locate on, in my case, worklightNode_1234.  This you can find
from the output in step 1.

4. Run the following command to check the status:

> curl -XGET http://localhost:9500/_cluster/health?pretty

The server status should be green when all the shards are initialized and assigned.

Comment: Hi TyLy would you mind also posting the configuration of the `jndi` properties in the server.xml file? 
I have the same issue you described and tried running the same commands, but I get an error `curl: (7) couldn't connect to host` when running the command from the same machine

Comment: Update: in my case, the problem seemed to be that I had too many shards configured. Reducing the number made the status move to YELLOW and the Console now loads

Comment: Hi Maggix, set jndi property in analytics server.xml in order allow access to 
Elasticsearch. 
<jndiName="analytics/http.enabled" value="true"/>

Comment: Hi TyLy @maggix I'm facing the same issue, i tried to check the shards using curl, but i'm getting the following result, curl: (7) couldn't connect to host.

i'm using MFP 7.1 on Windows machines and 2 MFP analytics clusters on Linux machines. I'm using WAS ND not liberty.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi @BasemTorky, as I wrote above I solved like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40855274/mobilefirst-analytics-dashboard-does-not-show-any-data/40855275?noredirect=1#comment70064863_40855275

Comment: @maggix How can i reduce the number of shards?

Comment: Hi @BasemTorky, Added my solution as answer as it's more readable than a comment

Answer (score 0):

On MobileFirst Platform 7.1, I solved the problem by changing the configuration in the `server.xml` file of the Analytics server, reducing the number of shards:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/shards" value="5" />
<jndiEntry jndiName="analytics/replicas_per_shard" value="1" />
```

For default values refer to: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_properties.html